# Is this photo of an aircraft in a flood genuine?

Tags: runways

I stumbled upon this picture somewhere on the internet:

[image]

I don't believe an aircraft would be able to take off like that; I also don't expect a normal landing be allowed if this were on a runway. I suppose, in case of emergency, it could possibly land into such water. Generally, I think that either this picture is fake or the aircraft was parked at a stand before the area was flooded.

Unfortunately, as the picture was so small, it's virtually impossible to see any details, and thus difficult to analyse for "fakeness". Could this picture possibly be real?

Comment: You might be able to [go through it if the engine is already running...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faDWFwDy8-U)

Comment: One clue that it is a fake is the reflection of the taxiway center-line under the nose of the aircraft.

Comment: How can "is this real" be an unclear question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the photo is a "Fake".

The photo was taken by Gary Watt of Aberdeen Scotland and then photo-shopped using the  "Flood Filter".

[PPRUNE explanation](https://www.pprune.org/showthread.php?p=1760339)

> Hi all
>   Amazing how this image gets around after posting it to someone some months back.
>   Yes, it's a fake. It's my photograph taken at ABZ and the 'Flood Filter' done in Photoshop.
>   Great tool and can produce some fantastic effects.
>   For all the doubters, the engines ARE running as it was taxiing to 34 for departure.
>   I can still confirm it\'s fake and if anyone else thinks different, ye need yer heids examined
>   Cheers
>   Gary Watt

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a larger version of the photo on [this web page](https://trynotlaughs.us/galleries/airplane-passengers-on-planes-memes-funny.html).  I also found some comments about it [here](https://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-161976.html).  Quoting from what someone said on that site: "There is no standing water anywhere else in the picture, there appear to be pilots in the cockpit, the leading edge flaps are set and there appears to be a lot of heat haze behind the starboard engine."

It's a fake.